# Powermock Failed to find the "modifiers" field in method setInternalState

Tags: powermock, powermockito, powermockrunner

I am trying to mock static class with Powermock. I am using JDK 14. However I am getting the below error:

```
Internal error: Failed to find the "modifiers" field in method setInternalState.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error: Failed to find the "modifiers" field in method setInternalState.
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.sedModifiersToField(WhiteboxImpl.java:2348)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.removeFinalModifierIfPresent(WhiteboxImpl.java:2312)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.setField(WhiteboxImpl.java:2298)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.setInternalState(WhiteboxImpl.java:304)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.setInternalState(WhiteboxImpl.java:317)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.setInternalState(Whitebox.java:190)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:119)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2489)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.sedModifiersToField(WhiteboxImpl.java:2342)
    ... 36 more
```

The test is working fine with jdk 1.8
testCompile("org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.4")
testCompile("org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.7.4")

It is a spring boot application.

Please advise

Thanks in advance.